# SSJS Wsproxy calling cloudpage resource from another ssjs script

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am extracting the Open/Sent/Bounce/Click/Unsub events and loading them in custom data extension.

I am using wsproxy to extract the data . The logic is .

1. I have custom cloudpage resource which takes 2 url parameters (startdate and enddate) and then extract approrpiate event info and loads in data extension.

--

```
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");
    var StartDate = Platform.Request.GetQueryStringParameter("StartDate");
    var EndDate = Platform.Request.GetQueryStringParameter("EndDate");
    try {
        var BUList = ["XXXXX", "UUUUU", "IIIII", "SSSSS", "QQQQQ", "PPPPPP"];

            for (var ii = 0; ii < BUList.length; ii++) 
            {
                var MID = BUList[ii];

                var filter = 
                {
                    Property: "EventDate", 
                    SimpleOperator: "between", 
                    Value: [StartDate, EndDate]
                };
                //Value: ["2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "2050-10-30T00:00:00.000Z"]
                var cols = ["SendID","SubscriberKey","EventDate","EventType","TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID","BatchID","Client.ID","ListID"]; 

                var logSentData = DataExtension.Init("Custom_SentEvent");

                var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy(),
                    objectType = "SentEvent",
                    moreData = true,
                    reqID = null,
                    numItems = 0;
                prox.resetClientIds();
                prox.setClientId({"ID": MID}); 

                while(moreData)
                {
                    moreData = false;
                    var data = reqID == null ?
                        prox.retrieve(objectType, cols, filter):
                        prox.getNextBatch(objectType, reqID);
                    
                    if(data != null)
                    {
                        moreData = data.HasMoreRows;
                        reqID = data.RequestID;
                        if(data && data.Results)
                        {
                            for(var i=0; i< data.Results.length; i++)
                            {
                                logSentData.Rows.Add({
                                    SendID: data.Results[i].SendID,
                                    SubscriberKey: data.Results[i].SubscriberKey,
                                    EventDate: data.Results[i].EventDate,
                                    EventType: data.Results[i].EventType,
                                    TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID: data.Results[i].TriggeredSendDefinitionObjectID,
                                    BatchID: data.Results[i].BatchID,
                                    ClientID: data.Results[i].Client.ID,
                                    ListID: data.Results[i].PartnerProperties[0].Value
                                });
                                numItems++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    } catch (e) {
    }
</script>
```

--
This works ok. I have tested this via Postman . I get the right data loaded into DE. The reason of using this approach is i can programitically control the timeperiod window and get data loaded in DE.

### For this purpose, i am using wrapper calling script.

```
<script runat="server" language="JavaScript">
    var StartDate = "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z";
    var EndDate = "2016-12-31T23:59:59.000Z";   
    

    /*Bounce-Start*/
    var url_bounce = "https://hsjhfjgdfgdjgdfjg.pub.sfmc-content.com/dfsdsfds?StartDate=" + StartDate + "&EndDate=" + EndDate;
    var contentType = 'application/json';
    var payload_Bounce = '';
    var resp_bounce = HTTP.Post(url_bounce, contentType, payload);
    /*Bounce-End*/
</script>
```

---

But the lower script is failing. i am not sure as to why.

In the child script (first one) , i dont need any payload. All info is passed using url parameters .

but somehow its failing and no error is given

Comment: I'd suggest you programmatically create /update an SQL Query instead and perform it via SOAP API, instead of mimicking the actual SQL operations with javascript.  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255137/soap-envelop-for-marketing-cloud-update-query-activity - makes a lot of things easier, is the right tool for the job and also will not expose an endpoint to the internet that anyone with the URL can use to call your script ...

Comment: Thanks Jonas. My understanding of your suggestion is to change the implementation of child script from wsproxy to soap. Soap is complex to implement than wsproxy so my prefernce is wsproxy . However the problem is not how the child is implemented, my main problem is calling child from parent/wrapper class . do you have any ides on how to do it

Comment: You can use WSProxy for updating a query activity as well. My point is you are using javascript for something that's better suited for SQL (extracting data from data views);- because it's less prone to running into limits (max 2500 records in SSJS retrieve) and doesn't need any custom API (which you need to secure, maintain etc.) for shifting data from one DE to the next. An sql query in the child BU that retrieves the data can just directly place it in a Shared Data extension to use it in the parent BU. Meaning that your process is more stable and your stated problem would simply not occur.

Comment: I would try using a GET instead of POST and also can try URL encoding the dates. As to if you should use the SOAP object or SQL, it is around the same general processing - the delay would be your manipulation of the data returned and then loading it into a DE. So if you are looking at a significant amount of data being returned, then likely using WSProxy calls to manipulate SQL queries and then starting an automation to run these queries would likely be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Gregory , my preference is wsproxy.  Actually i dont get any data back from child resource. all i want to give it the dates and trigger to start processing.  do you have any reference to similar example i can refer