# Marketing Cloud SOAP UpdateRequest for a QueryDefinition fails - Bad Request

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, query-definition

When I run (in Postman) the SOAP UpdateRequest for a QueryActivity below, I get 'Bad Request' as a response. What do I need to do to get this UpdateRequest working?

There's no example in the Marketing Cloud documentation of a SOAP call for updating a QueryActivity.

I modeled my call on this stackexchange answer, but it fails for me: [SOAP Envelop for Marketing Cloud - Update Query Activity](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/255137/soap-envelop-for-marketing-cloud-update-query-activity).

My code below shows oauth authentication. I've tried the same example with username/password. Both result in "Bad Request".

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:7e0cca04-57bd-4481-864c-6ea8039d2ea0</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
<soap:Body>
    <UpdateRequest
        xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Options></Options>
        <Objects xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
            <Client>
                <ID>1234567</ID>
            </Client>
            <ObjectID>279ef16d-28d3-47f4-aeb7-7cd777fb423a</ObjectID>
            <QueryText>select top 100 id, email, firstname as name from contact_salesforce</QueryText>
            <TargetType>DE</TargetType>
            <DataExtensionTarget>
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>
                <CustomerKey>66B2D386-4945-414D-841C-AB798F1F4826</CustomerKey>
                <Name>mc-1057_UpdatingDesAndQueries</Name>
            </DataExtensionTarget>
            <TargetUpdateType>Overwrite</TargetUpdateType>
        </Objects>
    </UpdateRequest>
</soap:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be specifying the the ObjectID.

Here's the upsert I use in Postman:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
        <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:b5b72bd6-a41e-4f3c-974c-d5360f393e91</a:MessageID>
        <a:ReplyTo>
            <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
        </a:ReplyTo>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}</a:To>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <ClientIDs>
                <ClientID>{{mid}}</ClientID>
                <ID>{{mid}}</ID>
            </ClientIDs>
            <Options>
                <SaveOptions>
                    <SaveOption>
                        <PropertyName>QueryDefinition</PropertyName>
                        <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
                    </SaveOption>
                </SaveOptions>
            </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
                <Name>TestDataExtension</Name>
                <CustomerKey>TestDataExtension</CustomerKey>
                <QueryText>select 'text@example.com' Emailaddress</QueryText>
                <TargetType>DE</TargetType>
                <DataExtensionTarget>
                    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
                    <CustomerKey>TestDataExtension</CustomerKey>
                    <Name>TestDataExtension</Name>
                </DataExtensionTarget>
                <TargetUpdateType>Overwrite</TargetUpdateType>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I can't get your example working, though it did change from the 'Bad Request' to an Error Code 2, which the MC documentation says is a System - General Exception. 

MC Support helped me get the example I put in the question working, so I'm all set. I'll post it in case anyone else is looking for the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Update</a:Action>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">{{soapEndPoint}}/Service.asmx</a:To>
      <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{accessToken}}</fueloauth>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options />
         <Objects xsi:type="QueryDefinition">
            <Client>
               <ID>{{mid_top}}</ID>
            </Client>
            <ObjectID>12a34567-67eb-4d96-a5e9-246f638c88a7</ObjectID>
            <QueryText>Select top 1 id as ContactKey from Contact_Salesforce</QueryText>
            <TargetType>DE</TargetType>
            <DataExtensionTarget>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true" />
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true" />
               <CustomerKey>a9876543-154f-454c-ae47-e88e9f2cd433</CustomerKey>
               <Name>AllFaculty</Name>
            </DataExtensionTarget>
            <TargetUpdateType>Append</TargetUpdateType>
         </Objects>
      </UpdateRequest>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```